# Necesito pasar el texto de un <div id="result"></div> a una variable php

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<select  id="select" for="exampleInputEmail" class="form-control" name='select'>

    <?php
    $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categoria"); 
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    ?>                                                                                               <option value=" <?php echo $row['id_categoria'] ?> " ><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>
    </option>                         
    <?php
    }
    ?>                                                
    </select>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('select').on('change', function() {
        var textohtml =  this.value;
        $('#result').html(textohtml);

      })
    </script>                                   
     <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En el titulo, pon un titulo a tu problema, que sea representativo. En la pregunta, explica lo que queres hacer. por ejemplo, de que div hablas? cual es el problema que tenes? que hace  y no hace esto?

Comment: Hola, estoy haciendo un select y se llena con datos de la BD, quiero que al seleccionar una opción saber cual se selecciono y pasar el dato a una variable php.

Comment: Cuando dices pasar el dato a una variable php te refieres a pasar el dato a otro archivo via ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder a un valor con jquery tienes que usar `.val();` y no `.value();` como lo haces en JS puro, además tienes que usar `$(this)` de esta forma, y no `this.`, seleccionas por etiqueta, te recomiendo uses el `id` ya que si tienes más `<select>` tendrías un problema y para mandar el valor a una variable PHP, tendrías que usar AJAX.

```js
$('#select').on('change', function() {
        var textohtml =  $(this).val();
        
        $('#result').html(textohtml);

        $.ajax({
          url: 'tuPagina.php', //mandas el valor a tu pagina php
          type: 'post',
          data: {valor: textohtml},//tomas el valor en php así $_POST['valor']
          dataType: '',
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            
          //aquí llega la respuesta del servidor
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<select  id="select" for="exampleInputEmail" class="form-control" name='select'>                                 <option value="">Selecciona...</option>
         <option value="gmail">gmail</option>
          <option value="yahoo">yahoo</option>
  </select>
  
 
                                 
     <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Como pasar el resultado de este  <div id="result"></div> a una variable php.

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.